# Get a list of global variables with IDA python

Tags: ida, idapython

I am trying to use IDA python to get a list of all variables in .data section because I want to extract a list of cross references to each global variables from IDA.
Is it possible to do this with IDA python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although [Sark](http://sark.rtfd.io/) is a good library/tool, if you're only looking for a small utility script you might want to avoid the overhead of installing it. I do  recommend you give it a try regardless.

The following code will do just that without using any third party code:

```
# get segment start and end EA by name
idata_seg_selector = idc.SegByName('.data')
idata_seg_startea = idc.SegByBase(idata_seg_selector)
idata_seg_endea = idc.SegEnd(idata_seg_startea)

# iterate EAs in range
for seg_ea in range(idata_seg_startea, idata_seg_endea):
  # iretate xrefs to specific ea
  for xref in idautils.xrefsto(ea):
    print("Found a cross reference {}: from {} to '.idata' variable {}".format(xref, xref.frm, seg_ea))
```

Gotaches:

- Using this code you'll see all cross references, not only those with a name, although adding that is quite trivial if you'd rather have it that way.
- As mentioned by @ws, you'll only see variables located at the `.data` section as the OP requested, you should consider including other data related sections (such as `.idata`, `.rodata`, `.bss`, and others). Alternatively you might want to consider using `idc.isData(idc.GetFlags(ea))` to filter out non-data offsets in some or all sections.

Comment: +1 but there are more segments that may contain global variables, .rodata and .bss in ELF for example

Comment: @w s that is what the OP has asked for

Comment: @NirIzr "because I want to extract a list of cross references to each global variables" . He probably didn't know about other segments.

Comment: @ws Thanks, edited to include your remark and a possible generic solution.

Comment: is there a way to do this AND get the name of global?  (dword_########)

Comment: @bravosierra99 That would be by just getting the address and calling the `Name` function. The default names for dword variables are in that format.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this. I am using [Sark](http://sark.rtfd.io) because it makes coding a bit easier.

The first option here is iterating over IDA's name list, and filtering by the addresses. The second one is going over all the lines in a segment, and showing those with names. In most cases, the first would be preferable.

import sark
    import idautils

```
# First option - names list
def get_segment_names(name):
    seg = sark.Segment(name=name)
    for ea, name in idautils.Names():
        if seg.startEA <= ea < seg.endEA:
            yield ea, name


# Second option - iteration over lines
def get_segment_names2(name):
    seg = sark.Segment(name=name)
    for line in seg.lines:
        if line.has_name:
            yield line.ea, line.name
```

To use them, just pass the name of the segment:

```
for ea, name in get_segment_names('.data'):
    print '{} at 0x{:x}'.format(name, ea)
```

Now, if you want xrefs, you can later do something like this:

```
def show_segment_xrefs(name):
    for ea, name in get_segment_names(name):
        print 'xrefs to {} at 0x{:x} from:'.format(name, ea)
        for xref in sark.Line(ea).xrefs_to:
            print '    0x{:x}'.format(xref.frm)


get_segment_xrefs('.data')
```

And get all the xrefs for the variables.

Comment: Upvoted to show my support for Sark :)