# Is it possible to get a list of user-defined names in IDA?

Tags: ida, idapython, python

IDA allows one to rename a program entity (e.g. register, variable, function) using `N` shortcut. Is it possible to get a list of such user-defined names in IDA?

Comment: Do you mean hex-rays variables by "variables" ? If yes, this script dumps almost all user defined things in specific decompiler function: https://github.com/idapython/src/blob/master/examples/vds4.py

Comment: In addition idautils.Names() can be used to retrieve the named global entities.

Answer (score 6):

The `idautils.Names` function might be of interest to you, as it returns a list of `(ea, name)` tuples for all names defined in the IDB and the ea at which they're located.

Additionally, you can use the answer to the question Igor linked ([Get a list of global variables with IDA python](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/get-a-list-of-global-variables-with-ida-python)) to get a list of all functions.

Once you have the `ea`s you can do the following to figure out if a function or ea was named by the user:

```
def is_user_name(ea):
  f = idc.GetFlags(ea)
  return idc.hasUserName(f)
```

This function will return true if an EA has a name set by the user either programatically or manually.

Comment: I think the `Names` utility function is available under `idautils`, not `idc`.

Comment: the API name is `idc.GetNames`, not `idc.getNames`. I can't make the edit because its less than six chars difference.

Comment: @WilliBallenthin Couldn't find a reference to idc.getnames anywhere in my comment. Let me know and I'll edit.

Comment: whoops, i'm sorry! I meant `idc.GetFlags()`.

Comment: `is_user_name` seems to return `True` even for library names that were generated during analysis.

Answer (score 3):

You can use View->Open subview->Names or <kbd>Shift-F4</kbd>. Note that the list included *all* names, both user-defined as well as generated by IDA (e.g. ASCII string names).

See also related [Get a list of global variables with IDA python](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13454/get-a-list-of-global-variables-with-ida-python?rq=1)

Comment: Is it possible to list out user-defined names only, not IDA generated ones?

Answer (score 1):

Run this .idc script to export all user-defined functions name. Script tested on IDA 7.0.

For IDA < 7.0: please use function **hasUserName(addr)** instead of **has_user_name(addr)**

```
#include <idc.idc>
static FuncDump(start)
{
    auto ea, str, count, ref;
    auto end;
    auto teststr;

    ea = start;

    while( ea != BADADDR )
    {
        str = GetFunctionName(ea);
        if( str != 0 )
        {
            end = FindFuncEnd(ea);

            count = 0;
            ref = RfirstB(ea);
            while(ref != BADADDR)
            {
                count = count + 1;
                ref = RnextB(ea, ref);
            }

            teststr = sprintf("sub_%X", ea);
            if(has_user_name(GetFlags(ea)) && !((GetFunctionFlags(ea) & FUNC_LIB) == FUNC_LIB) && teststr != str ) {
                Message("-s 0x%X=%s\n", ea, str );
            }
            //Message("%s, 0x%d, 0x%x, 0x%x, 0x%x, %d\n", str, count, ea, end, end-ea, end-ea   );
        }

        ea = NextFunction(ea);
    }
}

static main() 
{
    Message("FuncDump: Start\n");

    FuncDump(0x40000);

    Message("FuncDump: Done\n");
}
```